# Why is the ownership for /dev/input/eventX set to "root"?

Tags: permissions, dev

Why are `/dev/input/eventX` permissions/ownership set to `crw-r----- root.root`? Then no unprivileged user application can program the mouse.

According to what I've read it's due to security reasons, and I understand this. Yes, I also know that I can change `eventX` permissions via `udev`. But `/dev/ttyX` behavior is different, when not logged in, it is:

```
crw------- root.root
```

and once logged in, it becomes:

```
crw------- francesc.tty
```

Wouldn't it make sense to do the same for the mouse (`/dev/input/whatever`)? It seems a design inconsistency to  me.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

The mouse is a shared system hardware resource, and a `tty` is a local resource that a user can temporarily conjure into existence for personal use; I see no reason for the permission models to be similar)

What problem is it you are trying to solve by using the mouse device directly?

Comment: From a application design point of view I see keyboard (/dev/tty) and mouse (/dev/input/eventX) as equal citizens. I decide to use kbd as main input stream but later I change my mind and decide to use the mouse. Then I've a problem (obviously solvable) because I can open kbd but not mouse.

As a matter of fact, there are well known efforts to run X without **setsuid**, the how come it is X supposed to open /dev/input/eventX? Does anybody know the answer?